# Cors blocked while accessing APIs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, cors

I have a sample Login form developed using Reactjs-frontend, Nodejs (Backend) where I am trying to access a POST API to post form data (username and password) to Nodejs API for capturing data and process it in the backend.
Below is the code that I have written.

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*",
  allowedHeaders: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
  methods: "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const routesHandler = require("./routes/handler.js");
app.use("/", routesHandler)

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${port}`));
```

**routes/handler.js**

```
const router = express.Router();
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

router.post("/save_args", (req, res) => {
    const command_exec = spawn("python3", ["./server/login.py", req.body.user, req.body.password]);

    command_exec.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        res.send(data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**PostToPython.js** (ReactJs Component)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Button } from './Button';

export const PostToPython = () => {

    const usernameRef = React.useRef();
    const passwordRef = React.useRef();
    const [respFromServer, setResp] = useState({"output": "", "data": ""});

    const postToPython = async(e) => {
        const details = {"user": usernameRef.current.value, "password": passwordRef.current.value}
        e.preventDefault()
        const response = await axios.post(`//${window.location.hostname}:4000/save_args`, details)
        if (response.data.error){
            setResp({"output": response.data.error, "data": response.data})
        }
        else{
            setResp({"output": response.data.response, "data": response.data})
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <br />
            <form onSubmit={postToPython}>
                <label>Username: <input ref={usernameRef} required style={{
                        width: "5cm",
                        padding: "10px 20px",
                        boxSizing: "border-box",
                        border: "none",
                        margin: "8px 0"
                }}/></label>
                <br />
                <label>Password: <input ref={passwordRef} required type="password" style={{
                        width: "5cm",
                        padding: "10px 20px",
                        boxSizing: "border-box",
                        border: "none",
                        margin: "8px 7px"
                }}/></label>
                <br />
                <i>Try with username and password as admin, admin</i><br /><br />
                {respFromServer.output.includes("Successfully") ? 
                <i style={{ color: "greenyellow", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    {respFromServer.output}
                </i> :
                <i style={{ color: "maroon", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    {respFromServer.output}
                </i>
                }
                <br /><br />
                <Button type="submit" as="button" primary round>Submit-1</Button><br />
            </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default PostToPython;
```

Locally it is working fine, but when pushed to production (**[Netlify](https://laughing-sammet-8939ab.netlify.app/contact)**), it throws Cors block issue, that too waiting for sometime and throws below error.

[image: Cors Error]

Even Headers section doesn't show any response headers to view "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header; am i doing something wrong?

[image: Headers]

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are sent from the server, and your screenshot only shows Request Headers.

Your issue comes from the wildcard `"*"` origin specified in your `cors()` configuration. Only non-modifying methods (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD...) allow a wildcard. In your case (POST), the exact domain name + port of your client should be set, for example:

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: "https://your-client.example.com:3000",
}));
```

Comment: I have tried the above, but it still gives same issue; also there are no response headers when i access the API.

Comment: any other solution please?